Tab order not passed to a widget's children
I have a widget Edit Tool which has many elements. One of it's elements is custom widget, CustomSelector. CustomSelector has several child widgets which are dynamically generated.
My issue is with wrong tab ordering. Even if I put the correct tab order in the UI — it does not work and the tab goes to CustomSelector child elements only after it went through all the other widgets.
How do I set the tab order for CustomSelector child widgets properly? Preferably without hard-coding tab order widget names.
I tried setting tab order in Qt UI. I also tried using QWidget::setFocusProxy() expecting that when tab order comes to CustomSelector widget — it will go automatically to its children. It does not work, though.

Please provide a [mre] (read that page, please) so that others can test your code and see the problem on their machines. As it currently stands, the question is missing a lot of details, and someone trying to answer would have to make a lot of guesses about your UI structure and so on.
